# Problems connecting to SAP with sapnco

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

I am trying to connect to SAP with a little c# program using SAPNCO x64 v. 3.0.2 with this code:

```
public partial class Connection
{
    public class Configuration : IDestinationConfiguration
    {
        public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;

        public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
        {
            var Parameters = new RfcConfigParameters();
            if (destinationName == "TEST")
            {
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "...");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, "...");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "01");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.LogonGroup, "COMMON");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "...");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "...");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "...");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
                Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.MaxPoolSize, "10");
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException();

            return Parameters;
        }
    }

    public void ConnectionTest()
    {
        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(new Configuration());
        RfcDestination destination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("TEST");
        destination.Ping();
    }
}
```

When I call `Ping()` I get this error:

LOCATION   SAP-Gateway on host ... / ...

ERROR       Gateway not connected to local R/3

TIME        Mon Jan 29 19:43:34 2018

RELEASE     722

COMPONENT   SAP-Gateway

VERSION     2

RC          726

MODULE      gwr3cpic.c

LINE        5831

COUNTER     2

I can figure it out. Any would be appreciated. Thanx.

NB: I have replaced sensible data with dots, of course.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem replacing this line:

```
Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, SAPServeHost);
```

with this one:

```
Parameters.Add(RfcConfigParameters.MessageServerHost, SAPServeHost);
```

it was just a wrong configuration.

Comment: mmm when I tried the same change, the error changed to "partner '[hostnamehere]:' not reached"